# get city with react-native geolocation?

Tags: react-native, geolocation

Is it possible to get the **city** the user is in using the react native **geolocation API**?

For example, running after running `getCurrentPosition()`, using the **longitude** and **latitude** to get the city?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The navigator geolocation API is built on the [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API).

Therefore you will probably require a Google API to get the other details such as city country etc ,by reverse geocoding and calling the api as

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${lat},${long}&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Check for more details in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)

Alternatively, I would suggest you to use `react-native-device-info` and get IP Address [getIPAddress](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info#getipaddress) method

```
DeviceInfo.getIPAddress().then(ip => {
  // "92.168.32.44"
});
```

and check the location based on IP using [IPStack](https://ipstack.com/documentation)

```
https://api.ipstack.com/134.201.250.155?access_key = YOUR_ACCESS_KEY
```

Comment: I've tried `react-native-device-info`, but the IP address returns "0.0.0.0" when testing on a real device, and the real device is on cell service. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Seems weird, although it should give you the local IP. I get correct IP on my real device. Try checking if there is an issue related to it.